# Deleted git ssh keys by mistake

Tags: git

I deleted the .ssh folder with all my git keys by mistake. I don't want to lose the changes I have in my repository. How can I reconnect with my git server (local to our organization), without losing my existing local commits?

Comment: How is your setup on the server? Do you use gitolite or manual ssh configuration?

Comment: I don't know, the last time I set it up all I had to do is copy my public key over. The git server has an interface where I can just copy paste my public key. I can request to delete the old key and provision a new one through the interface.

Comment: Just do so, create a new key pair, provision the key and put the private key in your .ssh folder. git doesn't care what key you had when you created your commits.

Comment: If I create a new key, can I still keep my existing commits?

Comment: Yes, ssh is not involved in the local operation of git.

Comment: @xbonez make that into an answers so that they can be upvoted.

Comment: @Ozan make those into answers so that they can be upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh is not involved in the local operation of git. Create a new key pair, provision the public key and put the private key in you .ssh folder. Then you can push your local commits as usual.

Answer (score 3):

The ssh key only authenticates you with the server. You can set up a new one, add that to your git server, and continue working.

Create a new ssh key by running the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```